# sending a javascript object through websockets with faye

Tags: node.js, serialization, websocket, javascript-objects, faye

Hi all I'm trying to send a javascript object through websockets:

the faye-websockets documentation says:

**send(message)** *accepts either a String or a Buffer and sends a text or binary message over the connection to the other peer.*

server side I'm using node and faye.

```
var WebSocket = require('faye-websocket');
var http = require('http');

var server = http.createServer();
server.addListener('upgrade', function(request, socket, head) {
    var ws = new WebSocket(request, socket, head);
    ws.send({topic:'handshake', data:'sdf487rgiuh7'});
});
server.listen(8000);
```

client side:

```
<script>
    var ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8000');
    ws.onmessage = function(e) {
        console.log(e.data); //prints [Object object] string and not the object
    };
</script>
```

what is my error? Thanks

Comment: who give -1 explains the reason please..

Comment: The -1 is likely due to the fact that the error message has already told you exactly what is wrong.

Answer (score 106, accepted):

WebSockets support sending and receiving: strings, typed arrays (ArrayBuffer) and Blobs. Javascript objects must be serialized to one of the above types before sending.

To send an object as a string you can use the builtin JSON support:

```
ws.send(JSON.stringify(object));
```

To send an object as a typed array you can use a javascript BSON library such as [this one](https://github.com/schteppe/js-bson):

```
ws.send(BSON.serialize(object));
```

When you receive a WebSocket message you will need to deserialize it.

To deserialize a JSON string from a WebSocket message:

```
ws.onmessage = function (e) {
    var object = JSON.parse(e.data);
    ...
};
```

If you are using binary messages over WebSocket, then first you should set the binaryType attribute in order to receive all binary messages as typed arrays:

```
ws.binaryType = "arraybuffer";
```

Then the deserialization will look like this:

```
ws.onmessage = function (e) {
    var object = BSON.deserialize(e.data);
    ...
};
```

Here is a blog post about [using BSON in Javascript](http://granular.cs.umu.se/browserphysics/?p=1025);

Comment: Your link is dead :/ And there aren't any readme.md on the git repo of js-bson. Gonna search some doc.

Comment: Is it possible that the `onmessage` callback doesn't return the entire json string, and therefore `JSON.parse` throws a parsing error?

Comment: @MartinKonecny WebSockets is message based and messages are delivered in full (no partial messages). However, note that if you have something like websockify in the middle and you're actually talking to a regular TCP server on the other end, the message divisions are arbitrary (depend on TCP packet size, kernel window sizes, buffer sizes, etc). In that case you need to do some kind of re-assembly yourself.

Comment: Thanks, I thought websockets were just plain sockets initiated via http. Good to know to is message based.

Answer (score 3):

Client:

```
const bson = new BSON();
ws.binaryType = 'arraybuffer';

ws.onmessage = function(event) {
  console.log(bson.deserialize(Buffer.from(event.data)));
}
```

Server:

```
 const data = bson.serialize({ ... });
 ws.send(data);
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm basically working with Socket.IO, but it looks like you need to stringify your data in the server and parse it in the client like so:

in the server:

```
ws.send(JSON.stringify({topic:'handshake', data:'sdf487rgiuh7'}));
```

in the client:

```
console.log(JSON.parse(e.data));
```

Comment: in your case you are sending a string but since faye supports sending binary data I want to exploit this feature

Comment: @frx08 An JS object is no binary data, an image would be. So udidus answer is correct.

Comment: so the only method to serialize a js object is to stringify it?

Comment: "Stringifying" an object is another way to say "serialize with JSON"

Answer (score 2):

add a function called `json` to the websocket object that transform in json and send the object passed by parameter

```js
ws.json = (obj) => ws.send(JSON.stringify(obj));

ws.json({ message: "hello" });
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck

Answer (score 0):

From the client side you can just send it via `JSON.strigify` and in the server side just do `JSON.parse` to get the data

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).